Gnuplot - bar plot with bar labels rotated 90 degrees clockwise
I have this Gnuplot script:
reset session

$Data <<EOD
"Push-Front"            2344 0x289e37
"Push-Back"             187  0x289e37
"Insert"                1222 0x289e37
"Push-Front-Collection" 519  0x289e37
"Push-Back-Collection"  420  0x289e37
"Insert-Collection"     287  0x289e37
"Search"                191  0x28579e
"Pop-Front"             4939 0xa83232
"Pop-Back"              251  0xa83232
"Delete"                4771 0xa83232
"Delete-Range"          345  0xa83232
EOD

set style line 11 lc rgb 0xeeeeee lt 1 lw 1
set style fill solid 1.0
set boxwidth 0.8
set key noautotitle
set ytics 1000
set grid y ls 11
set tics scale 0
set tics out
set xtics rotate by -45
set terminal svg size 450,300 enhanced font "Times New Roman,12"
set output '..\msc-sandbox\TotalDurationBarPlotArrayList.svg'
set yrange[0:5000]
set ylabel "Milliseconds"
plot $Data u 0:2:3:xtic(1) w boxes lc rgb var#, \
        '' u 1:2:3 w labels offset 0,0.7

It looks like this:

What I want to achieve, is to add bar height values on top of each bar, rotated clockwise by 90 degrees in order for the labels fit in the plot.

You don't get your values on top

because you end your line with w boxes lc rgb var#, \ where #, \ comments out the following line
the plot command for the values should read u 0:2:2


You could also rotate your xticlabels by +45 or labels for the values by -90 degrees and align it right or left. That's just a matter of personal reading preference.
add some offset/margin at the top to get the numbers above the value within the graph area.

Script:
### bar chart with rotated xticlabels and values on top
reset session

$Data <<EOD
"Push-Front"            2344 0x289e37
"Push-Back"             187  0x289e37
"Insert"                1222 0x289e37
"Push-Front-Collection" 519  0x289e37
"Push-Back-Collection"  420  0x289e37
"Insert-Collection"     287  0x289e37
"Search"                191  0x28579e
"Pop-Front"             4939 0xa83232
"Pop-Back"              251  0xa83232
"Delete"                4771 0xa83232
"Delete-Range"          345  0xa83232
EOD

set style line 11 lc rgb 0xeeeeee lt 1 lw 1
set style fill solid 1.0
set boxwidth 0.8
set key noautotitle
set ytics 1000
set grid y ls 11
set tics out
set xtics rotate by 45 right
set yrange[0:]
set ylabel "Milliseconds"
set offset 0,0, graph 0.1, 0

plot $Data u 0:2:3:xtic(1) w boxes lc rgb var, \
        '' u 0:2:2 w labels offset 0,0.5 rotate by 90 left
### end of script

Result:


Sir, you are amazing! However, I have a couple of nitpicks: (1) how to get rid of the "tics" on top and right edge of the plot, (2) how to change the font of the bar names (such as "Push-Front" etc.) to Times New Roman?

@coderodde 1) you had it in your code set tics scale 0 or set tics nomirror. 2) as you also did in the definition of the terminal or set xtic  font "Times New Roman, 10" and/or in the plot command w labels offset 0,0.5 rotate by 90 left font "Times New Roman, 10"
